# Question on elementary number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $P_n=p_1p_2..p_n$ and $a_k=1+kP_n$ where $k=0,1,..,n-1$ and $p$'s are the primes 2,3,5,7,.. arranged in ascending order. Prove $\gcd(a_i,a_j)=1$ if $i$ is not equal to $j$.
My attempt is
Any prime $p$ in the range $p_1$ to $p_n$ does not divide $a_i$ and $a_j$.

Comment: Hi, please use Tex to write your question.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. Your attempt is the right idea. Suppose by contradiction that there is some $p$ that is a common divisor of $a_i$ and $a_j$ (with $i\neq j$, WLOG $i>j$). Then, $p\mid a_i-a_j=(i-j)P_n$. From here since $0<i-j\leq n$ and $P_n=p_1\dots p_n$, note that $p$ has to be one of the first $n$ primes, i.e. $p\in\{p_1,\dots,p_n\}$. Now, your approach tells you this is not the case, so a contradiction.

Comment: You should be more explicit about the claim that "$p$ has to be one of the first $n$ primes". What is your *complete* reasoning for that?

Comment: @Bill Dubuque $i-j\leq n$ so prime divisors of $i-j$ have to be smaller than $n$. I think it is clear that $p$ has to be one of the first $n$ primes.